# How do I mix different channels without the colors affecting one another?

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I'm trying to set up a Material that I can set the color of each channel individual through a color mask. I figured that much out however I'm trying to add them back together.

It will work initially however when I change the color of one channel it will start to affect the others.

I can't seem to find a node that will allow me to mix these different channels together.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Unreal available at the moment, so I can't give you a screenshot, but I try to describe it.

Instead of multiplying the color, you could just use a `Linear Interpolate` node to combine them one by one.

You plug the result of `Mask(R)` into a `Linear Interpolate` node as its `Alpha`. You then plug the color you want the `R` channel to be into `B`. You then create the next `Linear Interpolate` node and plug `Mask(G)` into `Alpha` and the result of the first `Linear Interpolate` into `A`, the color you want the `G` channel to be into `B`. Proceed with the next node until everything is covered.

How does this work?

Linear Interpolate uses [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) to map the values between `0` and `1` to whatever you plug into A and B. You can think of the Linear Interpolate node as a filter for a mask. If you want to combine two shapes onto another, you plug your mask-input into `Alpha` and everything in `B` will be seen instead of `A` when the mask is `1`. You can read more about this in [this article](https://joyrok.com/SDFs-Part-Two). You will find a lot of essentials under "Math Signed Distance Fields - COMBINE, BLEND, AND MASK SHAPES".

Comment: Thank you!

This worked quite well for me. the end results however after doing this for all six channels was quite dark so I multiplied the end result by a constant and was able to get some pretty good results.